# Синхронизация с 1С

Tags: 1с, синхронизация, битрикс

Новые позиции выгружаются нормально.

Затем в позициях в 1С вносятся изменения и выгружаются на сайт,
но только часть изменений синхронизируется, а некоторые позиции так и остаются со старой информацией.

Почему изменения некоторых позиций не синхронизируются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету техподдержки Битрикс отключили использование контрольных сумм элементов в настройках интеграции с 1С.

Пока все пашет.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что это Битрикс :))

При такой постановке вопроса очень сложно ответить правильно. Может быть не все позиции попадают в файл импорта, поэтому часть позиций не обновляется. Может быть позиции все попадают в файл импорта, но в них содержатся не все данные, например, артикул пропущен, может быть происходит ошибка в самом механизме импорта. Первое, что нужно сделать, это удостовериться, что файл формируется 100% правильно. После этого разбираться с скриптом, осуществляющим импорт.

Comment: В настройках стоит, что синхронизировать нужно только обновления.

Сравнивали две позиции ( одна синхронизируется, а другая нет ), в обеих заполнены все поля и идентичной информацией.

Попробую сделать файл выгрузки и посмотреть в нем.